# Store mysql results in array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have a very simple question.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".USERS."";
$result = $site_db->query($sql);

while ($user_row = $site_db->fetch_array($result)) {
    $user_id = $user_row['user_id'];
}
```

Now I need to use all the user_id (array) in:

```
$user_id = array();
foreach ($user_id as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

I need to **store the user_id in an array**.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you must learn about the php array..

Comment: PDO::FETCH_COLUMN will return array of values for fetchAll() or simple value for fetch()

Comment: Thanks DevPro en deep: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do like:

```
    while ($user_row = $site_db->fetch_array($result)) {
        $user_id[] = $user_row['user_id'];
    }
```

Comment: define $user_id = array(); before while loop :)

Comment: if query didnt return any record than it will break... initialize your array before loop.

Answer (score 2):

Store `$values` in an array like that:

```
$yourArr = array();
while ($user_row = $site_db->fetch_array($result)) {
  $yourArr[] = $user_row['user_id'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($yourArr);
```

**Result should like that:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123 // assuming userid
    [1] => 456 // assuming userid
    [2] => 789 // assuming userid
)
```

Comment: @AnnaZina: you are welcome actually all of us are on same point, now chose the best answer and mark as accepted this will help for others who facing this issue to. by clicking the left green tick.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
$user_id = $user_row['user_id'];
```

with

```
$user_id[] = $user_row['user_id']; // make $user_id variable array
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know how it works. I just voted or do I have to click somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You have a Database containing columns like user_id, user_name, from you question what you want to do is to get all the user_ids into an array, right?
Here is how you do it...

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM ".USERS."
";
$result = $site_db->query($sql);

$user_id = array();
while ($user_row = $site_db->fetch_array($result)) {
array_push($user_id, $user_row['user_id']);
}

//then you can use your array now
foreach ($user_id as $value) {
echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Comment: u are using array_push in a a while loop its an extra cost